# Draw solid cylinder with asymptote

Tags: asymptote, technical-drawing, tikz-graphdrawing

I want to draw an image like this with asymptote, but I don't know how to draw the cylinder part like in this image.

[image]

I try with this code

```
triple v=O;
real cyl_r=2;
real cyl_h=3;
triple axis=Z;
axis = X;
revolution r = cylinder(v, cyl_r, cyl_h, axis);
r = shift(-0.5*cyl_h,-ho,lf)*r;
// draw(surface(r),green,render(merge=true));
draw(r);
```

But the result is not as I expected, the cylinder is not solid

[image]

I want the cylinder image same as the first image

Comment: I suggest you to use http://ipe.otfried.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is not complete.

To have solid cylinders and silhouette you have to mix the 3D OpenGL (unitcylinder, unitsphere, etc...) and the `solids` package (to have silhouette of your cylinder).
For the construction I have created one function which draws a cylinder (solid and silhouette) and another function (a simple loop) to avoid a very long list of `triple` and axis.
The code is not perfect, there is one warning because I use the silhouette function.

```
import three;
import solids;
size3(10cm);
currentprojection=orthographic(600,450,200);

triple v=O;
real cyl_r=.4;
real cyl_h=.7;
triple axis=Z;

void cyl_oriented_shifted(triple pO=v, real r=cyl_r, real h=cyl_h, triple maxis=Z)
{
  // v should be the center
  // if maxis=O there is no cylinder, not very elegant
  if (maxis!=O)
    {        
      surface cylinder=shift(pO)*align(unit(maxis))*shift((0,0,-cyl_h/2))*scale(cyl_r,cyl_r,cyl_h)*unitcylinder;
      surface disq_cyl=shift(pO)*align(unit(maxis))*shift((0,0,-cyl_h/2))*scale(cyl_r,cyl_r,cyl_h)*unitdisk;
      surface disq_cyl1=shift(pO)*align(unit(maxis))*shift((0,0,cyl_h/2))*scale(cyl_r,cyl_r,0)*unitdisk;
      revolution rcyl = cylinder(pO-h/2*unit(maxis), r, h, maxis);
      material whitem =  material(diffusepen=white,emissivepen=white);
      draw(cylinder,whitem,render(merge=true));
      draw(disq_cyl,whitem);
      draw(disq_cyl1,whitem);
      draw(rcyl,black+1bp);
    }
}

void sequence_of_node_and_segment (triple [] T, triple [] AT, pen p1=currentpen)
{
  // T is the array of node
  // AT the array of associated axis for the cylinders or not if AT[i]==O
  for (int i=0;i<T.length;++i)
    {
      cyl_oriented_shifted(T[i],cyl_r,cyl_h,AT[i]);
      if (i<T.length-1)
        { // the segment
          draw(T[i]--T[i+1],p1);
        }
    }
}

pen pentige=black+2bp;
// lower part
triple[] RL={(0,0,0),(0,0,1), (2,0,4),(0,0,8),(0,3,8),(2,3,4),(0,3,1),(0,3,0)};
triple[] ARL={O,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,O};
sequence_of_node_and_segment(RL,ARL,pentige);

// arms
triple[] HRL={(0,-1.5,11), (0,-1.5,13.3),(0,-1.5,14),(0,0,14),(0,3,14),(0,4.5,14),(0,4.5,13.3),(0,4.5,11)};
triple[] AHRL={Y,X,O,Y,Y,O,X,Y};
sequence_of_node_and_segment(HRL,AHRL,pentige);

// to the upper part
triple[] HC={(0,1.5,8), (0,1.5,10),(0,1.5,14),(0,1.5,15.6)};//,(0,0,13),(0,3,13),(0,4.5,13),(0,4.5,12),(0,4.5,10)};
triple[] AHC={O,Z,Z,Y};
sequence_of_node_and_segment(HC,AHC,pentige);

draw(shift((0,1.5,8))*scale3(.2)*unitsphere,material(diffusepen=white,emissivepen=white));
revolution sph=sphere((0,1.5,8),.2);
draw(sph.silhouette(),black+1bp);
```

and the result. Please notice that the picture is not vectorized since the true 3D OpenGL renderer is used.

[image]

Comment: Hi, @O.G.  I have just test your code. I just paste your code to the webpage: http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/, it looks like the generated image is not the same as the one in the answer. Half of the cylinder is not shown. I change the line to `draw(cylinder,whitem); //,render(merge=true));`, then it works OK.  Here are two questions: 1, what dose the `render` argument in your code used for? 2, why there is a check of `maxis!=O` , what does the parameter `maxis` used for? Thanks.

Comment: I guess that the `maxis` is the direction of the axis of the cylinder. So, this vector should not be zero, am I correct?

Comment: @ollydbg23 : I proposed this code two years ago (and I have no answer). I have no idea about your question, only that the option `merge` is related to Bezier patches. Sorry. For `maxis`, you're right !